# Responsive Design for Mobiles

Tags: css, html, mobile, responsive-design, responsive-slides

I am new to HTML5 and I have created a website with home page having few icons with absolute position, fixed top and left values.

But when the same is opened in mobile device, I have to scroll a lot, and the images are not coming in center as expected.

Please let me know your inputs for same, as I am new to HTML5 and would like to learn different aspect.

Thanks & Regards,
Mrudul

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that those answering this question have something work with. Also let us know what you've tried, what went wrong and anything else you can think of that would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say you're using bootstrap to make things responsive. 
If thats the case, you can simple add a class to images to make them scale correctly..

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/1920x400"  class="img-responsive"  alt="">
```

You can copy and paste this in your editor to test it.
This way, if the screen gets smaller, so will your image.

EDIT :
Also, if you want the image to be contained in a wrapper you can use the following structure :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x400"  class="img-responsive"  alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are making some rather large assumptions there.